# Genesis' bVII-V-I cadence

Tags: theory, cadence

In the verse part of Genesis' "Behind the Lines", the last line of the chord progression goes:

F   C   Dm   **Bb G** -> C (resolution)

What is that cadence? What is the theory for that `bVII - V - I`?

I've heard a lot of times the double plagal cadence that goes `IV/IV (bVII) - IV - I`, for example in the outro of Hey Jude. But I could not find the correlation between the bVII and V chords.
I thought maybe it could be kind of a resolution where D stays the same, Bb goes to B and F goes to G (if voiced and inverted correctly); but it's kind of disorienting that the Bb is chromatic to the key...

Comment: Maybe because it wouldn't be used in the common practice preiod, there's no official name for it.

Comment: @Tim I'm not looking for a name but for a common analysis

Comment: What is the bass doing through these changes?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis that's a very good question, that I don't know the answer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rock harmony tends to be mostly root position, but if the bass held a `D` for the `Dm` and the `Bb`, you could possibly talk about passing motion, especially if there is a line like `A Bb B C`.

Mixolydian coloring may be the most straight forward way to describe this. Exclude the `Bb`...

`F C Dm ... G -> C`

...and you have common progressions `IV I` then `ii V I`.

Inserting a Mixolydian (borrowed) `bVII` between `ii` and `V` doesn't really change the essential harmony of root progression by fourths and fifths.

In terms of technical jargon [*borrowed chord*, *mode mixture*, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borrowed_chord) are terms that could be used.

Comment: That would be a good explanation. I don't know if there is criteria or theory for passing chords so...

Comment: passing motion, chords, etc. basically can be used when the tones don't fit a well defined, common progression, but the _linear_ motion is step wise. A classic passing chord is the `V6/4` in something like `I6 V6/4 I`. Passing chord in invoked for that description, because `6/4` chords (second inversion chords) are expected to be part of a cadence of pedal bass.

Comment: Try looking up passing tone, passing chord for a more complete description. Some counterpoint knowledge helps complete the understanding.

Comment: [Wikipedia: Borrowed Chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borrowed_chord) _"Chord progressions may be constructed with borrowed chords, including two progressions common in rock music, I–♭VII–♭VI–♭VII, common everywhere, and I–♭VI–IV, used by bands like **Genesis**, Yes, and Nirvana."_

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be considered a **line cliché** where the A in the Dm chord goes to Bb and then to B in the G chord.

Comment: I was going to call it that, but isn't a line cliché a progression where only one note changes chromatically (and the others stay the same)?

Comment: But it would actually make sense, since then it resolves to C (going A Bb B C)

Comment: I don't think it's necessary for all the other notes to stay the same. *Stairway to Heaven* has other notes move.

Answer (score 0):

The B♭ chord could very well be a borrowed chord from C Minor. In C Minor, it behaves as an ordinary non-tonic, non-dominant chord. In C Major, it will behave the same way.

In any cadence, it's the last two chords that are by far the most important. I wouldn't put any significance on the ♭VII part of a ♭VII - V - I cadence.